# How to prove the following statements $1$ and $2$ about function limit are equivalent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, epsilon-delta

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on interval $(a,b)$ and let $l$ be a real number.

$1.$  $\forall t>l,\exists\epsilon >0,\forall x\in(a,a+\epsilon),f(x)<t$ and

$\ \ \ \ \forall t<l,\forall\epsilon >0,\exists x\in(a,a+\epsilon),f(x)>t$

$2. $ For all the sequences $s_n$  in $(a,b)$ such that $s_{n} \to a$ and the sequence $f(s_n)$ converges, $l$ is the largest of the limits $\lim f(s_n)$ obtainable in this way.

My thought:

The original definition of limit of right end is $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,  \forall x\in(a,a+\delta), |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$

$\rightarrow:$ Assume $1$, suppose $2$ is false, then there is a larger limit, say $m$. But then I don't see how making $m$ a larger limit would violate the statement $1$

$\leftarrow:$ Assume $2$. Let $t$ be a limit larger than $l$ then there is no such sequence on $(a,b)$ such that $f(s_n)$ converges to $t$. Negating the original definition we get  $\exists \epsilon>0,\forall \delta>0,  \exists s_n\in(a,a+\delta), |f(s_n)-t|\ge\epsilon$. But I don't see a connection to statement $1$.

Could someone help?

Comment: Something is wrong with the problem as stated because 1 and 2 are not equivalent. For example, let f(x) = x, (a,b) =(0,1), l = 0. Then Statement 1 is true, but the largest limit $f(s_n)$ of any sequence in (a,b) is 1, not 0, so Statement 2 is false.

Comment: The sequence $s_{n} $ must tend to $a$ for these two statements to be equivalent. The number $l$ is actually limit superior of $f$ as $x\to a^{+} $ and we write $l=\limsup_{x\to a^{+} } f(x) $ or $l=\overline{\lim\limits_{x\to a^{+} } }f(x) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh $\lim\sup$ seems a great idea, but since $\lim\sup$ is a limit about a sequence, how do we translate so the different $f(s_n)$ can be seen as a unique sequence, and thus we can make connection to the first statement?

Comment: Wherever you can define a limit you can also define a $\limsup $. So it is not only restricted to sequences. Anyway  you need to edit your second statement by writing "any sequence $s_{n} $ in $(a, b) $ with $s_{n} \to a$..."

Comment: You should start your argument by noting that there is some special sequence $a_{n} $ such that $f(a_{n}) \to l$ and for any other sequence $s_{n}$ we have $f(s_{n}) \leq l$. Using this you can easily show the properties mentioned in first statement.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh for $1\implies 2$, I wonder if such contradiction works: Suppose $1$ holds, let $s_n$ be any sequence on $(a,b)$, then $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N,\forall n>N, |s_n-a|<\epsilon$, this implies $s_n\in(a,a+\epsilon)$, now suppose there is a larger limit $m$ than $l$ such that $f(s_n)$ converges to, then $\exists m>l, \forall \epsilon>0, \exists s_n\in (a,a+\epsilon),\  |f(s_n)-m|<\epsilon$. The issue here is how do we translate $|f(s_n)-m|<\epsilon$ into $f(x)>t$ so that the negation of first part of $1$ happens?

Comment: You assume $m>l$ and then we have $m>(m+l) /2=t>l$ and from first statement we see that $s_{n} \in(a, a+\epsilon) \Rightarrow f(s_{n}) <t$ and taking limits as $n\to\infty $ we get $m\leq t$ contrary to $m>t$. This is how we use the first part of 1. We have shown so far that limit of any sequence $f(s_{n}) $ does not exceed $l$.we next need to show that there is a sequence for which this limit is equal to $l$. Here you will need second part of $1$ also.